# Rails7 Docker環境構築ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

### 環境

M1
Docker version 20.10.16

### 概要

Dokcer環境でRails7プロジェクトを始めようとしていますが、エラーが吐かれて解決できません。
お力を貸していただきたいです。

ファイルは下記サイトのものをコピーして使用しています。
https://mseeeen.msen.jp/rails-docker/

### 各ファイル

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM ruby:3.1

RUN apt update -qq && apt install -y postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

*Gemfile*

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.2'
```

*entrypoint.sh*

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

exec "$@"
```

### エラー

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

複数のサイトで環境構築を試してみたのですが、どれもこのエラーが出てきてしまい解決できませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。
特定のbundlerのversionで不具合が発生していたようでした。
bundler v 2.3.3に変更したところ解決です。